# Arduino Ultra Sonic Sensor always returns 0

Tags: arduino, arduino-ultra-sonic

I am doing a basic project in **Arduino UNO** connecting an **Ultra Sonic sensor** (HC-SR04) which should print in the serial monitor the distance of the closest object but it always print 0.

This is my code:

```
long distance;
long time;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(2, INPUT); 
}

void loop(){
  digitalWrite(2,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);

  time = pulseIn(4, HIGH);
  distance = int(0.017*time); 

  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm.");
  delay(1000);
}
```

And this is the breadboard:

[image]

Comment: just curious, do you have an `int()` function defined somewhere?

Comment: No I don't.  Should I?

Comment: your computation `distance = int(.0.017*time)` would suggest so.  see https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping?from=Tutorial.UltrasoundSensor for an example code.

Comment: Here http://www.instructables.com/id/Ultrasonic-Range-detector-using-Arduino-and-the-SR/ too

Comment: @KevinDTimm If I remove the ```int``` function the issue persists. I tried to follow that post but the author uses a different sensor (it has 3 pins). I have also tried with different pieces of codes that I found in blogs and the issue is the same.

Comment: @KevinDTimm I will try with those instructions. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinDTimm, The Arduino library has the `int()` function.  Which "Converts a value to the int data type".  It's weird, but it does actually exist.

Comment: @embedded_guy - thanks. I've done a little arduino but, being a C guy, I wouldn't call the function I'd cast the result :)

Comment: @KevinDTimm - I am with you on that.  I think that using a function like `int()` just adds confusion.  I have coded a lot in C and I think it is more straightforward to cast the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary issue that I see is that your code doesn't match your wiring diagram.

For example, your diagram shows **Trig** connected to pin 4.  The **Trig** should be the output from your Arduino but you have it defined as an input.

The **Echo** is connected to pin 2 and it should be an input, but you have it defined as an output.

Finally, in your `loop()`, you are not even using pin 2 or pin 4, but pins 9 and 8.  Another issue is the timing you use in setting the trigger pulse - it does not match the datasheet.  I would do something like this (assuming that you are actually connected to the pins shown in your diagram):

```
#define sensorTrigPin    4
#define sensorEchoPin    2

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(sensorTrigPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(sensorEchoPin, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int pulseWidth = 0;

    digitalWrite(sensorTrigPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(10);
    digitalWrite(sensorTrigPin, LOW);

    pulseWidth = pulseIn(sensorEchoPin, HIGH);

    Serial.print("Pulse Width: ");
    Serial.print(pulseWidth);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Note that `pulseWidth` is just the amount of time that it takes from the beginning of the **Echo** pulse going high to the end of the same pulse (when it goes low).  You would still have to calculate the distance based on the value of `pulseWidth`.

---

**UPDATE BASED ON RECENT EDIT TO THE QUESTION**

If you change a portion of your `loop()` code to this, it should work:

```
void loop(){
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH);   //was (2, LOW)
    delayMicroseconds(10);   //was (5)
    digitalWrite(4, LOW);    //was (2, HIGH)
    //REMOVED EXTRA DELAY

    time = pulseIn(2, HIGH);  //was (4,HIGH);
    ...  //Keep the rest of your code the same.
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I tried your code but seems to be missing the duration declaration.

Comment: I can uploaded without errors but now nothing is printed in serial monitor :s

Comment: @ianaya89 This is just a suggestion, but it helps if you do not change the code in your original question if it can be helped.  You have made modifications to your code that have created a moving target when it comes to answering your question.

Comment: Yes I know that, but I changed the code because I have copied it wrong. This is my original code and the issue is the same. Sorry for that!

Comment: I tried and the behavior is the same: pulseWidth is always 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81917/discussion-between-embedded-guy-and-ianaya89).

Comment: As you suggested was an issue in the wires, anyway your code was very helpful. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ianaya89, Great!  Glad you were able to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting your **VCC of the sensor to 3V3** instead of 5V. This might sound odd, but I tried it and it worked well. Also, please make sure that your echo and trig pin match the code.